# Protocol for remote process management

Tags: distributed, protocols, process-management, remote-process

**In short:** Is there any known protocol for remote process management?

I have a system that contains several applications, each has it's own computer in a local network. When the applications are up and running, they communicate without any problems.

What I'm interested in is a protocol to manage the remote applications startup, shutdown and monitoring. By monitoring I mean getting error codes (predefined) when something goes wrong. Ideally I would control the whole system from one managing application and get status about what's going on.

I once worked in a place that wrote an in-house protocol that did this. However, I wish to avoid writing it again if someone already figured this out.

**Edit:** some more details:

- Platforms in use are Windows and Linux, both on x86.
- On Windows, C/C++ and .NET are used. On Linux, C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with homegrown solutions instead of using tried and tested technology? Unless you only employ programmers who are MENSA members with 30+ years of experience, your solution will be less robust and costlier to maintain.

You failed to mention any details about the platform you're using, so I'll assume a Unix-ish system. I would go with (and have been going with for years)

- SNMP for monitoring
- either daemontools or cron + scripting (as a distant second choice) for supervision and restart
- ssh/scp with RSA authentication for interactive intervention, remote command execution, and occasional transfers

Comment: I've added some more details. Isn't SNMP an overkill for this?

Comment: I have no way of knowing whether it's overkill or not - I've used it successfully to monitor 2 nodes, and to monitor 250 nodes. You'll have to evaluate. But keep in mind that project scope always grows, and in 2 years you might be glad you chose an extensible solution.